# What is the upper limit (maximum limit ) of WinRM MaxShellsPerUser

Tags: powershell, limits, winrm

For executing the remote powershell commands i need to configure WsMan, In WsMan MaxShellsPerUser specifies the maximum number of concurrent shells that any user can remotely open on the same computer. If this policy setting is enabled, the user will not be able to open new remote shells if the count exceeds the specified limit. If this policy setting is disabled or is not configured, the limit will be set to 5 remote shells per user by default.

Default is 5 and what is the maximum limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Policy Definition, the maximum value for `MaxShellsPerUser` is 2147483647 (equivalent to `[Int32]::MaxValue`, indicating no practical upper limit).

Comment: Thank you very much @Mathias R. Jessen, May i know the information source

Comment: Yes, I inspected the Administrative Template file on my Windows 8.1 Enterprise machine: `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\WindowsRemoteShell.admx` - line 64 contains the value definition for the `MaxShellsPerUser` setting